# Order by rating, then by time created

Tags: mysql, sql

I've made a simple service where you can post rows and other people can rate them.

I want it to be ordered by rating, as it is now, and then ordered by time created. This would result in ratings above 0 at the top. First of these will be the latest.

My SQL ends like this:

```
ORDER BY d.rating DESC,
d.created DESC
```

...But it does not give me the wanted result. What am I missing?

Comment: A SELECT at the start? But seriously you should add a few more details, I can't see an apparent problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use:

`ORDER BY d.rating, d.created DESC`